# What happens when you multiply two tables with the same attribute names?

Tags: mysql, sql

Say you're taking the cartesian product of two tables, R and S, and both have two attributes, A and B which are the same data types too.

If I multiply them, will the resulting table be `A B A B` or `A B` somehow?

Comment: why don't you try it yourself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will get all the attributes, no matter they have the same name or not. And this is true for all other `JOIN` types as well and any other table operators. So:

```
CREATE TABLE R (A int, B INT);
CREATE TABLE S (A int, B INT);

INSERT INTO R VALUES(1, 2), (2, 3);
INSERT INTO S VALUES(1, 2), (2, 2);

SELECT *
FROM R CROSS JOIN S
```

Will give you all the attributes in the two tables like so:

```
A   B   A   B
1   2   1   2
2   3   1   2
1   2   2   2
2   3   2   2
```

However you can limit the attributes you want to select in the `SELECT` statement. Something like `SELECT T1.A, T2.B`.